# extracting an img source link from a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have this string

```
#<Fletcher::Model::Amazon alt="You Are Not a Gadget: A Manifesto (Vintage)" border="0" element="img" height="240" id="prodImage" onload="if (typeof uet == 'function') { if(typeof setCSMReq=='function'){setCSMReq('af');setCSMReq('cf');}else{uet('af');uet('cf');amznJQ.completedStage('amznJQ.AboveTheFold');} }" onmouseout="sitb_doHide('bookpopover'); return false;" onmouseover="sitb_showLayer('bookpopover'); return false;" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51bpl1wA%2BaL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg" width="240">
```

I simply want the link in the src attribute:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51bpl1wA%2BaL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg"
```

How can I parse this string to get the link

Below is a listing of relevant functions

```
module Fletcher
  module Model
    class Amazon < Fletcher::Model::Base
      # A regular expression for determining if a url comes from a specific service/website
      def self.regexp
        /amazon\.com/
      end

      # Parse data and look for object attributes to give to object    
      def parse(data)
        super(data)

        case doc
        when Nokogiri::HTML::Document
          # Get Name
          self.name = doc.css("h1.parseasinTitle").first_string

          # Get Description
          self.description = doc.css("div#productDescriptionWrapper").first_string    

          # Get description from meta title if not found
          self.description = doc.xpath("//meta[@name='description']/@content").first_string if description.nil?

          # Get Price
          parse_price(doc.css("b.priceLarge").first_string)

          # Get Images
          self.images = doc.xpath("//table[@class='productImageGrid']//img").attribute_array
          self.image = images.first
        end            
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your string looks suspiciously like it's the output of calling `inspect` on a Ruby object; do you have the actual object itself?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I am not entirely sure what "actual" object you are referring to. The whole gem (fletcher) is on github. https://github.com/hulihanapplications/fletcher. I've included the classes and methods above.

Comment: Well, how did you get that string in the first place?

Comment: fletchedProduct = Fletcher.fetch http://www.amazon.com/You-Are-Not-Gadget-Manifesto/dp/0307389979....
fletchedProduct.image

The documentation for fletcher says that fletchedProduct.image.url should give me what I want.

Unfortunately, that seems broken

Comment: You could always just use regex to pull it out.

Comment: I just read over the method. Doesn't the self.image pull it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case I believe it would be: fletchedProduct.image[:src]

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'open-uri'

x = %Q{#<Fletcher::Model::Amazon alt="You Are Not a Gadget: A Manifesto (Vintage)" border="0" element="img" height="240" id="prodImage" onload="if (typeof uet == 'function') { if(typeof setCSMReq=='function'){setCSMReq('af');setCSMReq('cf');}else{uet('af');uet('cf');amznJQ.completedStage('amznJQ.AboveTheFold');} }" onmouseout="sitb_doHide('bookpopover'); return false;" onmouseover="sitb_showLayer('bookpopover'); return false;" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51bpl1wA%2BaL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg" width="240">}

url = URI.extract(x)

puts url[2]
```

output:

```
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51bpl1wA%2BaL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU01_.jpg
```

Hope this helps. I just happened to need to be able to do this last week and looked it up.